# Android GridLayout images

Tags: android-layout

I am trying to implement grid layout with image an text :

Each item have a text and an image and an action. This is how it should look:

[layout grid](https://www.google.tn/search?q=Egypt%20Yellow%20Pages&biw=1366&bih=667&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=t8CbVaSvA4XMygOP16OwCg&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAg#imgrc=1rdpaaRPYHV65M%3A)

Comment: Pretty sure the Android developer page on grid layout will guide you on the right path here - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

I followed the same page a few weeks back whilst attempting to do the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this as layout for your grid item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/picturetext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="#55000000"/>
```

This will give you result something like below.
[image]

Now to get the result as required in your sample you can change the width and height of alternate elements i.e modulo 2 elements. For even index items you can have square size dimensions and for odd index items you can have rectangular items.

Set the adapter for your gridView using this code.

```
GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagegridview);
gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));
```

Use this class as the image adapter.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context localContext;
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

    ImageAdapter(Context ct){
        this.localContext = ct;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(localContext);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageTweets.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v;
        ImageView picture;
        TextView name;

        if (convertView == null) {
            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.new_grid_item, parent, false);
            v.setTag(R.id.picture, v.findViewById(R.id.picture));
            v.setTag(R.id.picturetext,    v.findViewById(R.id.picturetext));
        } else
            v = convertView;

        picture = (ImageView) v.getTag(R.id.picture);
        name    = (TextView) v.getTag(R.id.picturetext);


        picture.setImageUrl(imageTweets.get(position).entities.media.get(0).mediaUrl, mImageLoader);
        name.setText(imageTweets.get(position).user.screenName);

        return v;
    }
}
```

In my case I am using url to load image therefore above code.
In your case you can directly set the image from resources. See if it works.

Comment: can you please accept the answer and upvote if it was of any help to you. Thanks